# How to generate md5 with php and mysql

Tags: php, sql-server, md5

Okay, my database accepts passwords as md5. I tried to generate the md5 from my registration page and insert it into the database. thats my code here:

```
$str = md5($pass2);
mssql_query("DECLARE @AIDIdent int INSERT INTO UserInfoFromPublisher (fdUserID,fdGameID,fdPassword,fdCash) VALUES ('".$username."',NULL,'".$str."'),10000) ");
  echo '<p class="errormsg">The account "'.$username.'" has been successfully made!</p>';
}
```

i used

> $str = md5($pass2);

then put it into the mssql query.. it doesn't seem to work.. any help?

Comment: Consider switching to `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`, `md5()` is not secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have typo mistake and unwanted )closing bracket.. use this

```
  $str = md5($pass2);
  mysql_query("DECLARE @AIDIdent int INSERT INTO UserInfoFromPublisher (fdUserID,fdGameID,fdPassword,fdCash) VALUES ('".$username."',NULL,'".$str."',10000) ");
   echo '<p class="errormsg">The account "'.$username.'" has been successfully made!</p>';
                        }
```

Comment: I want to do the same with the login... to check if the password is right, any idea how I can make it decrypt the md5? and check if its the same as the string i wrote?

Comment: dear Alex md5 is one way encryption function.. you cant decrypt md5 So for that ..you need to use mysql encryption and decryption function

Answer (score 0):

Check th following query:

```
INSERT INTO UserInfoFromPublisher (fdUserID,fdGameID,fdPassword,fdCash) 
VALUES ('".$username."',NULL,'".$str."'),10000)
```

here last value **1000** is out of the round closing bracket **)**

Change it to:

```
INSERT INTO UserInfoFromPublisher (fdUserID,fdGameID,fdPassword,fdCash) 
    VALUES ('".$username."',NULL,'".$str."', 10000);
```

and try again.

Comment: Sounds great !!

Comment: i want to do the same with the login... to check if the password is right, any idea how i can make it decrypt the md5? and check if its the same as the string i wrote ?